# Steam dosen't start, an X error occured

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d, steam

whenever I try to run steam, it doesn't open, but it doesn't give an error message. Running it through the consle, I get this...

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2013-08-21 21:24:50] Startup
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
```

I am sure my computer meets the requirements, and steam works on my windows partition.
Also, I am running Ubuntu 12.04, in Unity 2D

Answer (score 0):

## Install Additional Drivers

Install the proprietary video drivers by doing the following:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center (Centre if you're not American)
2. Navigate to the universal menu towards the top of the screen and select Edit->Software Sources.
3. Wait for the window to come up.
4. Select the tab Additional Drivers.
5. Select a proprietary driver if it's available and install it.

## Intel Card AccelMethod

WRITE DOWN THIS ANSWER SO IF YOUR VIDEO BREAKS YOU CAN TRY THE REVERT SECTION.

### Change

Try this in a terminal (`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`T` to open):

```
sudo su
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bkup
nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Navigate to the section `Device` and add this line:

```
Option "AccelMethod" "XAA"
```

Do `Ctrl`-`X` and `Y` to save. Then run `reboot`.

### Revert

If things go wrong or don't change, and they may, do this:

```
sudo su
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bkup /etc/X11/xorg.conf
reboot
```

If you're in only a terminal (no graphics), then these commands will work if you log in. Note you will need to type in your password for the `sudo` command.

Let us know how it works.

Comment: Hmm... i get the error "cp: cannot stat '/etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory"

Comment: What's the error, where is it, and does it change anything?

Comment: I just fixed my previous comment.

Comment: I added a bunch more. Try the first one first.

Comment: I didn't see an additional drivers tab, but I found it through the lens. It searched for drivers, then output "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system." There weren't any options, except Help and Close.